# How to escape single quote in Vtiger Webservice

Tags: web-services, vtiger

Does anyone know how to escape a single quote (') when executing a query with the Vtiger webservice?

I've tried the following:

- select * from Contacts where lastname = "O'Connor";
- select * from Contacts where lastname = 'O\'Connor';
- select * from Contacts where lastname = 'O\\'Connor';
- select * from Contacts where lastname = 'O%'Connor';
- select * from Contacts where lastname = 'O%%'Connor';

The error that I get is:

```
{u'error': {u'code': u'QUERY_SYNTAX_ERROR',
 u'message': u"Syntax Error on line 1: token 'Connor' Unexpected COLUMNNAME(Connor), expected one of: SEMICOLON",
 u'xdebug_message': u"\nWebServiceException: Syntax Error on line 1: token 'Connor' Unexpected COLUMNNAME(Connor), expected one of: SEMICOLON in /var/www/sites/vtigercrm6_test/include/Webservices/VTQL_Parser.php on line 1499\n\nCall Stack:\n    0.0001     221800   1. {main}() /var/www/sites/vtigercrm6_test/webservice.php:0\n    0.0163    3089752   2. OperationManager->runOperation() /var/www/sites/vtigercrm6_test/webservice.php:134\n"},
 u'success': False}
```

[Vtiger Webservice Reference](https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservice_reference_manual)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out - double single quotes!!

```
select * from Contacts where lastname = 'O''Connor';
```